# Decoding Unicode in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a function that gets a string encoded in Unicode `\u05D4\u...` as a variable `str` and I want to change that Unicode into letters, so that this `str` will contain the translated string.

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't name your variable str. It is a type in python

Comment: Your naming is backwards; your string is Unicode, and it's already got letters in it. You want to *encode* it into bytes.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read and/or watch http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html (this goes for everyone even seeing this question if they haven't seen this site before...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually **two** types of strings we could be dealing with here.

The first is a **Python Unicode string**, where the string is already a set of unicode points.

This is what it looks like in Python:

```
>>> x = u"\u1129\u1129"
>>> x
u'\u1129\u1129'
```

You can actually just print this to the screen, because the Python print function usually uses an encoding that supports this. (I believe it is sys.stdout.encoding)

```
>>> print x
ᄩᄩ
```

If you wish to encode this, you should probably use the utf-8 encoding, which supports all known Unicode characters. However, you will still need the print function to print it as a readable character.

**But**, this kind of string is easy to print! I doubt you would have any trouble outputting this to the screen. Which is why I believe you have the second type of string:

The second type of string is a **Unicode-escaped string**, which can be found in things like Java .properties files (where they force you to use some single-byte variant of ascii encoding). This is what it looks like in Python:

```
>>> escapedString = "\\u05D4\\u05D4\\u05D4"
>>> print escapedString
\u05D4\u05D4\u05D4
```

And then because whoever designed these files was ignorant of [Unicode and the basic essentials of character encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), it's our job to turn these escaped code points into readable characters.

```
>>> pythonUnicode = escapedString.decode("unicode-escape")
# This turns escaped unicode code points into Python unicode code points
>>> print pythonUnicode
ההה
```

And it looks like we have readable characters!

However, you should be careful if you have characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0 to U+FFFF). There are different ways to encode characters that extend past the basic two bytes. For example:

Python escapes extended characters with `\U` (note capital U) and an eight-char.

```
>>> print "\\U0001D11E".decode("unicode-escape")

>>> print u"\U0001D11E"
```

But the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifies a different kind of escape:

> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
>   Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence,
>   encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
>   containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
>   "\uD834\uDD1E".

So make sure you know where your data comes from!

Comment: Note that in the second case there are a number of different formats that use `\u` escapes - Python unicode literals (which `unicode-escape` handles), Java properties, JavaScript string literals, JSON, and so on. It is important to know which one you are dealing with because they all have slightly different rules about what other escapes are valid. `unicode-escape` may or may not be a valid way of parsing that data depending on where it comes from.

Comment: @bobince Thanks, I did not know that. Added a bit more information. Added some more links. Threw away my dream of Unicode being a magical unifying standard.

Answer (score 0):

Encode string as unicode on assignment and use `print` to correctly prompt escaped characters:

```
>>> s = u'\u05D4\u...'
>>> print s
ה
```

Answer (score 0):

Use u'..' to declare an unicode string and use UTF-8 to encode it (UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding that can represent every character in the Unicode character set).

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python
a = u'\05D4\05D4'
print a.encode(utf-8')

>> xx
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have the string in Unicode, and you want to translate it to displayable characters, you will need to select your encoding. I'll assuming you want to display it on your terminal, and your running windows?

```
ustr = u'\u05D5'
print ustr.encode('latin-1')
```

Now here's something funny. The sequence you quoted in your example does NOT map to any legal characters in the latin-1 encoding, so I recommend you always specify 'replace' as your error handler. ie:

```
print ustr.encode('latin-1', 'replace')
```

NOTE:

I see the character set is intended to be hebrew

```
print ustr.encode('hebrew', 'replace') # alias for iso8859_8
```

Comment: I wasn't offending anyone. The OP did NOT specify encoding. I guessed at Windows latin-1 -- to demonstrate HOW to encode. I then tested it, and saw it did not cleanly encode to latin-1, so I showed an example of error handling. But now I'm being labelled as insensitive because I somehow read his mind or have committed every codec to memory?