# Unicode and subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, subprocess

I have a field in a sqlite3 db that contains strings like:

```
title = "Friedrich_N\u00FCrnberg"
```

I read this strings in a variable and I want to pass the unicode version of it to a subprocess.Popen call.

The software I am calling through Popen needs to receive as input this:

```
Friedrich_Nürnberg
```

instead of this:

```
Friedrich_N\u00FCrnberg
```

otherwise the its computation is vain.

This is the calling code:

```
subprocess.Popen([command, title], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How can I modify it?

Thanks a lot.

PS. If I manually try adding a u"" it works, but I cannot use that syntax because I am not explicitly stating the text content of each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a Unicode escape sequence. The desired character you want is called an encoded character.

Here is an example of decoding unicode escape sequences in the Python shell.

```
>>> title = "Friedrich_N\u00FCrnberg"
>>> character = title.decode("unicode-escape")
>>> character
u'Friedrich_N\xfcrnberg'
>>> print character
Friedrich_Nürnberg
```

You could try:

```
title = title.decode("unicode-escape")
subprocess.Popen([command, title], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I wrote another answer which I think explains this fairly well.
[Decoding Unicode in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908739/decoding-unicode-in-python/21909580#21909580)

Comment: @michele: if you need `.decode('unicode-escape')` then something is wrong in your data chain. Fix the code upstream that generates the string to produce Unicode strings or bytestrings in a known encoding instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian perhaps the poster does not control the upstream data.

Comment: @icedtrees: we don't know. It means that the first option is to fix upstream. If we can't fix upstream. We can't

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I suggest you specify this in your first comment. "something is wrong in your data chain" is very misleading. Often software restrictions force one to store unicode in escaped sequences, and there is nothing "wrong", per say, with that.

Comment: @icedtrees: yes. It is wrong. If the exchange is in memory then it should use Unicode strings. If it stored externally (disk, network) then something like `json` could be used (it even uses similar Unicode escapes). You should not see `unicode-escape` in your code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The poster clearly specified that a sqlite3 database was the external data source. The poster did not specify where the database data came from. I am simply saying, when you do not know details about the data source in the question, please do not make assumptions and start calling solutions "wrong". `unicode-escape` clearly worked in this scenario - if you have a problem with it please explain why your method is more helpful. Stack Overflow is a place to help solve problems, not to enforce opinions on data storage.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're absolutely right. The solution is to write and retrieve to/from the DB UTF-8 strings instead of text. I'll investigate how to do it...

Thanks a lot for your support guys.