# Call Popen with unicode path

Tags: python, unicode, subprocess, python-2.x

I have a unicode string. When I print it it, copy and paste it into the CMD and press Enter - it's all working well.
But When I call the function `subprocess.Popen()` with that command string it doesn't work, Python says there is no such file in the path and prints a path in gibberish (the unicode part in the original string is replaced with weird looking characters).

Assume I have the string (actually a `type<unicode>`) called `s` (by the way, my string contains a command running a python script from an external folder, so it looks something like this - `"python 'C:/path/to/file/file.py' arg1 arg2'`), I can do:

```
print s #this works, even just copying and pasting it manually into the command line works fantastically
subprocess.Popen(s, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #prints 'python: can't open file [gibberish path]: Errno 2 no such file or directory'
```

And the reason why I don't use any other function aside of `Popen()`, say `system()` or `call()` is because I need the output of the program.

Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with interpreting the string as utf-8 - if python thinks it is another encoding than utf-8 it might encode it wrongly, is this python3?

Comment: If the string looks wrong when printed, how do you know that it's correct?

Comment: @gauteh Nope, 2.7.11

Comment: @dorian It looks okay when printing, only wrong when python prints it. I rephrased the question now

Comment: It might be a problem with the shell that is started by subprocess; if that messes up the unicode argument it gets, Python can't do anything with it. Typically, the shell started by subprocess is more bare bones than your usual shell.

Comment: Is the type of `script_name` `unicode` or `str`?  If the latter, what encoding is it in?  Is it the same as the encoding returned by [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding)?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475791/unicode-and-subprocess-popen) on subprocess and unicode of any use?

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the clarification. I agree with gauteh et al. that it's likely an encoding issue.

Comment: @jwodder It's unicode, utf-8. And it's not the same, the encoding returned by the function you stated is mbcs.

Comment: @Jonathan: If the variable is of type `unicode`, it can't be UTF-8, as that only applies to characters encoded as byte sequences (i.e., `str` objects).  Is there a `script_name.encode('utf-8')` expression you're not showing us?

Comment: @jwodder Nope, I was just confused. It is of type unicode, though.

Comment: I rephrased the whole question, might be worth to look at the changes, maybe it's even more clarified now

Comment: In Python2, convert unicode string to bytes using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` (which may be occasionally be `None` or wrong, so please test a few systems)

Comment: @qarma It actually did work! Thank you

Comment: related: https://bugs.python.org/issue1759845