# python code open(encoding='utf8') is not working

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have a json file and I want to open (read and write) them without displaying as unicode :

json file as below :

```
{"A":"\u0e16"}
{"B":"\u0e39"}
{"C":"\u0e43\u0e08\u0e27"}
```

I tried below code but is not working (still open as encoded unicode) :

```
with open("test.json",encoding='utf8') as in_data:
    for line in in_data:
        print(line)
```

Expected output :

```
{"A":"ณ"}
{"B":"คุ"}
{"C":"ของ"}
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908739/decoding-unicode-in-python/21909580

Comment: Your input file is not encoded as UTF-8. Or perhaps it is, but `"\u0e16\"` is just a set of 9 characters: ", \, u, 0, e, 1, 6, \ and ".

Comment: i edited the last \" but i think it is still not working

Comment: @9769953 ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 and therefore an all ASCII file is valid UTF-8.

Comment: A warning about `print`. The `print` may not understand Unicode (in 2021 it is typical in Windows). So you should add a `print('{"A TEST":"ณ"}')` at beginning, just to be sure you are not getting two problems in once (so interaction and difficult to debug)

Comment: @MarkTolonen True, unless the encoding is e.g. ISO-8859-1, which overlaps in ASCII with UTF-8, but certainly isn't valid UTF-8 overall. For the example data given, it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file isn't valid JSON, but is what's called "JSON Lines Format" where each line is valid JSON.  You also need to decode the JSON line to display it properly.  The `json.loads()` function takes a string and decodes it as JSON:

```py
import json

with open("test.json",encoding='utf8') as in_data:
    for line in in_data:
        print(json.loads(line))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 'ถ'}
{'B': 'ู'}
{'C': 'ใจว'}
```

Answer (score 0):

when working with json files, you have to decode them before using:
first `import json`
then:

```
with open("jason.json", encoding="utf-8") as in_data:
    dict_from_json = json.load(in_data)
    for k, v in dict_from_json.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Also, you can place the for loop outside the `with open` block

There is also an error in your json file if you want to decode it as is, it should be written that way:

```
{"A":"\u0e16 ",
"B":"\u0e39",
"C":"\u0e43\u0e08\u0e27"}
```

as you can see here, the json file must be either a dictionary-like object or a list, you can read more about it in the docs

Comment: "you can place the for loop outside the with open block": that would mean opening and closing the file every iteration of the for loop, which is inefficient.

Comment: @9769953 The file is read once and then stored in the variable: dict_from_json. Then the for loop will iterate through the dictionary. It does not read the file, so you are effectively done with it the moment it is stored in this variable.

Comment: Sorry, read it the wrong way: I read it as putting the for loop around the `with open` block. Not as a separate block below it.

Answer (score -2):

You opened the file but didnt read it.
To read the file you have to add

```
lines=in_data.readlines()
```

after this you can write

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Also its utf-8

Comment: `for line in in_data` reads the file line by line.

Comment: Both 'utf-8' and 'utf8' will work.

Comment: Please test your piece of code before proposing an answer

Answer (score -3):

There is just a small error,instead of encoding='utf8' you have to use **encoding='utf-8'**

Hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: "utf8" is a supported alias for "utf-8" see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).